# AngularJS - hide a div when clicking in an inner element using a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to hide a box when clicking on a link inside this box.

I wan't to use a directive to be able to add more code when once the box is hiden and to keep it generic so I can use that with other views.

I've tried to use isolated scope but I guess I did it the wrong way.

Here is a fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/rJvqf/

I have a in my controller :

```
$scope.hideLoginBox = false;
```

In my view I have a div with ng-hide="hideLoginBox"

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    <div class="base" ng-hide="hideLoginBox">
        <p>outer</p>
            <div class="child">
                <a href="" my-test="" hidebox="hideLoginBox" >
                    innner
                </a>
            </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I click on the link I want to hide this div using the directive myTest.

I can't figure out how to do this.

Thanks for your help!

Regards,
Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nearly there.  You just needed a `scope.$apply` because you were in an element's `bind` event and I changed it to bind to `click` instead of `mousedown`.

Here is a [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rEqpW/).

Changes:

```
  element.on('click', function(event) {
    scope.hideLoginBox = true;
    scope.hidebox = true;
    scope.$apply();
    console.log(scope);   
  });
```

Comment: Thank's a lot for your help!